# Select element in document using JQuery

Tags: jquery, element

How can I write this?

```
$('document #filters input')
```

I've tried:

```
$(document).$('#filters input')
```

Comment: There is no need to do that since `$('#filters input')` already selects elements within the document...

Comment: I think you have a typo in the second, remove one dollar sign `$(document).('#filters input')`

Comment: @JimboSlice That won't work either

Comment: @imtheman: I'm using Ajax and when using a back button it doesn't work.

Comment: @imtheman, you're right, of course he don't need to call the document. that's what threw me off + i'm sleepy =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `document`, it should be:

```
$(document).find("#filters input");
```

or the equivalent:

```
$("#filters input", document);
```

`document` is a variable. Unprefixed names in a selector are tag names, not expanded as variables, so your selector was looking for a `<document>` tag somewhere.

Comment: Probably the second, since it's one function call instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$("#filters input")`. In your first example you are treating "document" as an element and in your second example, the code is incorrect. Look up jQuery's `.find` method for more help with the latter.

Comment: I'm aware of how to use $("#filters input") and I assure you I need the $(document) part.

Comment: @rotaercz Why do you need to use `$(document)`?

Comment: I'm using Ajax to load the content. When using the back button it fails.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and it is used like so:

```
$(document).filter('#filters input');
```